# _SESSION variables missing when running CRON script

Tags: php, cron, session-variables

I have a PHP script which checks on a _SESSION variable (upon creating a session, I'm setting the following var **$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']=time()** ).

The script has access to the relevant session id.
It sets the session id, starts the session, and checks the variable.

When I run the script manually, it works perfectly. It starts the session the was previously started and retrieves the _SESSION variable.

However, when the same script runs via CRON, the _SESSION variable is not set...

Any idea why?

Comment: You're calling the PHP on the crontab using which command?

Comment: What is the frequency, the session is probably already cleaned up.

Comment: This probably has something to do with the way your PHP environment is set. Just a hunch here: when running the script manually, are you using the same user and environment settings as CRON does?

Comment: alganet: I'm using a shared godaddy server, so I dont know which command runs the crontab.
jeroen: The problem is not related to session cleanup, since it set to 1 hour. And again, when running the php script manually (via http), I can access the _SESSION var. But with CRON, it shows as an unset var.
Lior: I checked the user issue already. Using logs, I can see that it's the same user for both CRON/non CRON request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call `session_start()`, php looks for the session id in $_COOKIE, and sometimes $_REQUEST. These dont exist on the command line version, as there's no webserver.

You can manually specify the session id via `session_start($id);`

make sure the `session.save_path` setting is the same between webserver and command line php versions. They can be different. Check via phpinfo() on both versions.

Comment: Is there a difference between using session_id($sessionId) followed by session_start() and what you proposed? Also, I'm using a godaddy server and the session.save_path is not the default one. How do I check the command line version?

Comment: no difference. you can just call phpinfo() from the script as normal, or do `php -i`

Comment: Ok, I can see that command line session.save_path has indeed a different value (I think it's the default one: /tmp). I will change the webserver to /tmp as well and update if it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, that was the issue. Can you tell me if there is a way to change the command line session.save_path? keep in mind I'm using a godaddy shared server so I'm a little limited. Maybe some way to set it via CRON?  Thanks again!

Comment: just add more arguments to the cron command, http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php, `php -d session.save_path=foo` or specify a path to a custom php.ini file.